# How to solve OOM exception while working with Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop, android-bitmap

I'm working with `Bitmap` and my workflow looks like this:

1. I get the photo and saved it to storage. Then present it to the user with
   help of `glade` lib.
2. If user approves the photo, I crop the face from photo and ask user approve it
   one more time. This way the user needs to make 5 photos each photo take
   him 2 steps of prove.
3. I work with a Samsung S5, and when I take a picture first time everything is
   ok, but the second time I get an error.

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.fittingroom.newtimezone, PID: 7196
            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
            Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 63489036 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 60MB until OOM
                at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:882)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:858)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:478)
                at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.getCroppedBitmapFromPath(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:65)
                at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.access$200(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:16)
                at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept$1.doInBackground(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:41)
                at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept$1.doInBackground(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:31)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is the snippet of code that I use to crop the image:

```
private Bitmap getCroppedBitmapFromPath(String path) {
    final File photo = new File(path);
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    Bitmap result;
    final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    final double centerX = height * 0.5;
    final double centerY = height / 447 * 480;
    final double widthAndHeight = height / 447 * 160;
    final int pointY = (int) (centerX - widthAndHeight / 2);
    final int pointX = (int) (bitmap.getWidth() - centerY - widthAndHeight / 2);
    final int widthAndHeightResult = (int) widthAndHeight;
    result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, pointX, pointY, widthAndHeightResult, widthAndHeightResult, matrix, false);

    return result;
}
```

There is nothing special just some calculations and I create a `new Bitmap()` instance...

According to the log file I get error exactly in this line:

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

Why don't I get this issue with first photo, only with second one?

Maybe bitmap cache stored some data and than when I try to do the same with second photo it is overflowing? How I can release cache and purge it?

Or maybe another solution? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How large are the files you're attempting to open?

Comment: @clownba0t file has original size about 6mb (depending on camera device)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant height and width in pixels. Remember that bitmaps can use up to 4 bytes for each pixel (depending on their configuration). My understanding is that attempting to load, say, a 10MP photo with dimensions 3,872 x 2,592 at full size could take around 40MB of memory.

Comment: @clownba0t sounds about right... But there are two questions 1) Why I get it with second photo, not with first one? 2) In this case could you give me advice how to reduce this size? But don't chenge size of origin image that had stored on device...

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, let's take this to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128172/how-to-solve-oom-exeption-while-working-with-bitmap

Comment: Did you check this post on android developers site?
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html